Altering rotary dimmer to have more range of motion while maintaining values?
I'm making a lamp right now and the vision is to have a dimmable lamp in which there are two strings controlling to the potentiometer. To increase the brightness, one string is pulled down and the other will go up. I have a lamp with a rotary dimmer on it right now and I figure the best way to do this is to attach the string to the knob.
The problems I'm attempting to solve are:
1: the range of motion on the knob translates to about 1 inch on the string. Ideally I'd like to pull the string about 5 inches or so to cover the whole range of the dimmer.
and 2: the knob takes a bit of force to turn, and I would like to make it a little bit easier so I don't knock over my lamp when im adjusting the brightness.
Looking for input as to solutions for these problems as well as if anybody has a a completely different idea as to how I should approach this.

I’m voting to close this question because it's a mechanical problem, not an electronic one.

This is a mechanical problem, not electronic.
To increase the distance you have to pull the string, you need a larger diameter knob/pulley.  The larger diameter pulley will also give you a longer lever arm to turn the potentiometer, so should reduce the force needed to turn the shaft.

you may find a suitable pulley inside an old radio receiver, about 54mm diameter should get you 5" movement

@JasenСлаваУкраїні Sounds like the sort of thing I could find inside my 3D printer. ;-)

yeah, there's many different ways to manufacture pulleys.

You could also use a multi-turn potentiometer with a smaller diameter pulley/wheel. A 10-turn pot is of course overkill electronically as it's intended for ultra-precise adjustment of sensitive equipment and might set you back $10-15 but if it saves you an hour of mechanical design then maybe it's worth it.

Very cool idea! It seems I've posted a mechanical question on this electrical forum but these ideas have been very helpful! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, I just didn't know it existed. It looks like these are a bit bigger than what is currently in there but I can figure that out. Somebody in another forum said it's actually not a potentiometer, but a rheostat that's in there so I gotta figure out the difference! Lol, thanks for your help!

A more advanced solution would be to eliminate the original dimmer completely and use a rotary encoder.
Take the signals from the encoder and decode them with a microcontroller. Depending on your firmware, you can scale the number of pulses from the encoder into a number of bits for a DAC (on or off chip).  From the output of the DAC, you are going to need interface circuitry to emulate what the original dimmer signal looks like.
For example, if you want a lot of string travel, you can scale the encoder down a lot (say, 100 encoder pulses for one DAC bit). If you want it to be very sensitive, you can change the scaling to be one-to-one.
The advantages of using an encoder and microcontroller is that you can pull the string forever after the min or max brightness is reached - there's no mechanical stop. The other advantage is that you can gamma-correct the brightness and/or program other sophisticated dimming curves.

It's a long way from a piece of string on a knob to an encoder feeding a micro, driving a TRIAC and all with mains safety, etc. d:^)

That does sound like a long way from my neanderthal string solution, but I'm interested in this as an option! I like the idea of not having a mechanical stop and I think that's what I was going for initially. Definitely going to be reading up on this. Would this only work to control an LED bulb?

@LiamKeith It would be one hell of a project with respect to what you are trying to achieve requiring knowledge of several engineering disciplines, some of which (at)Transistor alluded to in the previous comment. But appreciable skills could be learned in the process. The good news is that after you complete this project, the skills, technology and methods are transferable. And no, this doesn't only have to control an LED bulb. You can make it control anything you want with 90% of the project reusable - only the last stage has to be tailored to what you're controlling aka the driver stage.

For an LED light, an easy way to avoid the mains voltage issue Transistor raised would be to make the lamp an enclosed low voltage fixture with built in LEDs, rather than a conventional LED bulb. The use a fixed DC adapter and only dim in low voltage.
